Expansion Tile overflow
I am using Expansion Tile in the Enter Address manually layout and I've found that there is overflow. I try to fix it using ternary operator where I adjust it from Expanded to SingleChildScrollView. The reason I use it because if I use SingleChildScrollView, the button will only being shown half in the layout and we need to scroll it. How do I fix it?
enter image description here
Here's my code below
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Address extends StatefulWidget {
  const Address({super.key});

  @override
  State<Address> createState() => _AddressState();
}

class _AddressState extends State<Address> {
  FocusNode addressText = FocusNode();
  bool _open = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Container(
          width: 200,
          child: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(10.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: 1, // Value for first step
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xD9D9D9D9),
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 7.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: 1, // Value for second step
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xD9D9D9D9),
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 7.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: 0.15, // Value for third step
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xD9D9D9D9),
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ),
      body: _open ? SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0,vertical: 12.0),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-1/9*(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Enter your address",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22,fontFamily: "GraphikMedium"),),
                  SizedBox(height: 12,),
                  Text("Enter the street address of your primary residence. Please do not use a PO box or business address",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontSize: 16),),
                  SizedBox(height: 24,),
                  Text("Search for Address",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,fontFamily: "GraphikMedium",
                      color: addressText.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                  Focus(
                    onFocusChange: (focus){
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: addressText,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)
                        ),
                        hintText: "Enter your address",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 40,),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Theme(
                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
                      child: ListTileTheme(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        dense: true,
                        child: ExpansionTile(
                          title: Text("Enter Address Manually",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                          onExpansionChanged: (bool val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _open = val;
                            });
                          },
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                  Text("Address line 1",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                                      ),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                      )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                  Text("Address line 2 (optional)",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                  Text("City",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                  Text("City",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/user-purpose');
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Continue",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: "GraphikMedium",
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))
                    ),
                    minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size.fromHeight(60.0)),
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                    shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ) :
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0,vertical: 12.0),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-1/9*(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Enter your address",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22,fontFamily: "GraphikMedium"),),
                  SizedBox(height: 12,),
                  Text("Enter the street address of your primary residence. Please do not use a PO box or business address",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontSize: 16),),
                  SizedBox(height: 24,),
                  Text("Search for Address",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,fontFamily: "GraphikMedium",
                      color: addressText.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                  Focus(
                    onFocusChange: (focus){
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: addressText,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)
                          ),
                          hintText: "Enter your address",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 40,),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Theme(
                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
                      child: ListTileTheme(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        dense: true,
                        child: ExpansionTile(
                          title: Text("Enter Address Manually",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                          onExpansionChanged: (bool val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _open = val;
                            });
                          },
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                  Text("Address line 1",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                  Text("Address line 2 (optional)",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                  Text("City",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                  Text("City",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/user-purpose');
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Continue",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: "GraphikMedium",
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))
                      ),
                      minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size.fromHeight(60.0)),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                      shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I think I have the behavior you're looking for, demonstrated by this dart pad.
The idea is that you want the Continue button to always be on screen, so it shouldn't be in a scrollable portion of the Widget tree (so outside of SingleChildScrollView). Conversely, whatever other widgets you want to be scrolled should be in the scroll view, in this case I'm assuming it's the expansion tile contents, both when it is expanded and not. Because you want that scroll view to take up all the space that remains after the AppBar and Continue button are placed, they need to be Expanded.

umm not really actually I want the height of the body extend along with the Expansion Tile so it wont overflow but thank you very much, I just learn new thing. I didn't know we can apply SingleChildScrollView like that, I thought we need to use Floating Action Button in order to achieve what you did. Thank you

So you want the continue button to move up and down with the expansion/contraction of the expansion tile? But also make sure the continue button is always on screen, is that right?

u have to wrap Column with SingleScrollView in this part of your code.
child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [

i tried and it worked. But i dont understand usage of _open variable. U dont need _open variable and
 Expanded(
              child: Container(
                // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0,vertical: 12.0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                    1 / 9 * (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          "Enter your address",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 22, fontFamily: "GraphikMedium"),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 12,
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          "Enter the street address of your primary residence. Please do not use a PO box or business address",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 24,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Search for Address",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              fontFamily: "GraphikMedium",
                              color: addressText.hasFocus
                                  ? Colors.blue
                                  : Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 8.0,
                        ),
                        Focus(
                          onFocusChange: (focus) {
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: TextFormField(
                            focusNode: addressText,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                                hintText: "Enter your address",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 40,
                        ),
                        SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Theme(
                            data: Theme.of(context)
                                .copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
                            child: ListTileTheme(
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              dense: true,
                              child: ExpansionTile(
                                title: const Text(
                                  "Enter Address Manually",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",
                                      fontSize: 16.0),
                                ),
                                onExpansionChanged: (bool val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _open = val;
                                  });
                                },
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 8.0,
                                        ),
                                        const Text(
                                          "Address line 1",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",
                                              fontSize: 16.0),
                                        ),
                                        TextFormField(
                                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.grey)),
                                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                    color: Colors.blue),
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 8.0,
                                        ),
                                        const Text(
                                          "Address line 2 (optional)",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",
                                              fontSize: 16.0),
                                        ),
                                        TextFormField(
                                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.grey)),
                                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                    color: Colors.blue),
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 8.0,
                                        ),
                                        const Text(
                                          "City",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",
                                              fontSize: 16.0),
                                        ),
                                        TextFormField(
                                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.grey)),
                                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                    color: Colors.blue),
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 8.0,
                                        ),
                                        const Text(
                                          "City",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",
                                              fontSize: 16.0),
                                        ),
                                        TextFormField(
                                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.grey)),
                                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                    color: Colors.blue),
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/user-purpose');
                        },
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                            minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                const Size.fromHeight(60.0)),
                            backgroundColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                            shadowColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        child: const Text(
                          "Continue",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: "GraphikMedium",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

widget i think.
